# replay the commit history from a specific commit forward on a separate repo

Tags: git

I git-svn converted an SVN repo to a git repo. It had 1000 commits. All that history is in the new git repo, and I've made an additional dozen or so commits on top of that. However, I wish I'd started fresh, with a simple git init on the working copy of the SVN repo at its 1000th commit. I have that working copy to start from, and I can git init it for a new git repo. However, I'm having trouble replaying the dozen or so new, git commits on that. I've gone around in circles with archive, reset, rebase, fetch, merge, and several other commands. I even tried to simply squash away the 1000 lines of history, but it leaves me in a merge minefield for some reason. How do lop the top off the new repo and reply those efforts on the even newer repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but are you aware of git-cherry-pick?
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html

Comment: I knew it existed, but didn't realize it was what I needed. Thanks.